# Ionic state change issues on iOS 9 post version update to 1.1.1

Tags: ionic-framework, ios9

Confirming that i have updated Ionic to 1.1.1, so assuming the iOS9 webview patch is included in it. However, i am still facing issues with side menus onclick of which i am invoking $state.go() which does not render the actual page & reverts to original state. UI is completely broken.

Below is the system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:  
Ionic Version: 1.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.10
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.8.3 
ios-sim version: 5.0.3 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v0.12.7
Xcode version: Xcode 7.1.1 Build version 7B1005
```

HTML Code in the side menus:

```
<ion-item menu-close href="#" ng-click="getWishlist()" ng-if="userId && userId != ''">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col col-20">
              <i class="ion-heart"></i>
           </div>
           <div class="col col-80">
               My Wishlist
           </div>
      </div>
</ion-item>
```

JS Code in getWishlist():

```
$scope.getWishlist = function (){
    $state.go("app.wishlist", {}, {reload: true});
}
```

Help appreciated!

Note: Static URL invocations within menu seem to work just fine!

```
<ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/contact-us"  >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-20">
                  <i class="ion-ios-telephone"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-80">Contact Us
                </div>
            </div>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i guess it was my bad for not reading this [post](http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/) properly!

I figured the issue was due to `href='#'`. The post does mention to remove empty href links if necessary which invoke the `otherwise` state in iOS 9. Once i removed them the links started to work as expected.

However, i still had to alter my CSS to make the side menus look proper.